# Laravel stock allocation

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I'm trying divide(allocate) stock of a product to multiple teams. I have something that works, but it doesn't feel it is the correct way to do it.

A product have a total quantity/stock. (Available stock)
The available stock will be divided manually to each team.

Models:

**Products** 
ID
text -> name
integer -> stock

**Teams**
ID
text -> name

**Allocation**
ID
team_id
product_id
qty

**Team model:**

```
public function allocation()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Allocation::class)->selectRaw('SUM(qty) as qty')->addSelect('team_id')->groupBy('team_id');
}
```

**Blade of show.product:**

```
@foreach($teams as $team)
  {{ $team->name }} : {{ $team->qty }}
@endforeach
```

It works, but it feels like I found a workaround to get my results.
As well I will need the possibility to update the allocation of multiple teams of one product in the same form. I tried a few things to accomplish that, but it feels like I have to find a new workaround to get it done.